# Am I the only one who would like to see nested comment threads?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I may be completely off base here but I can't help but feel that allowing nesting of comments would be helpful.  By nested comments I mean something similar to reddit where you can reply directly to a user.  Many times I will ask for clarifying details in the comments of a question.  By the time the OP has answered and I get back to reply there are several comments between my question, OP's answer, and my reply.  This makes it difficult to follow the flow of the conversation especially when there are multiple questions and answers in the comments.

Do we, as a community feel as though nested comments would be beneficial or do we think it would just clutter things up?

Comment: Good lord above, no.

Comment: Further reading: [Jeff Atwood's take on nested comments](https://blog.codinghorror.com/web-discussions-flat-by-design/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a userscript for that at Stack Apps: [Threaded comments](https://stackapps.com/q/2050/26088).

[image]

So anyone who wants the feature could install it, but I think implementing this as standard would lead to more 'conversations' in comments, because it would look like it's alright to do so, but it's not; that's what Chat is for! :)

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for.  Good point about the conversations I guess I didn't consider that.

Comment: So to answer the title question, apparently, no you aren't the only one given the app, but judging by the votes, you are in the minority

Answer (score 9):

Comments are intended to server as quick, easy and **short** way of asking for further informations/explanation if required, not for extended discussions (which get moved to chat promptly), and the only thing that nested comments would be good for are extended discussions, so thanks, but no thanks.